# create db as innodb in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I knew that we can set innodb as engine tables. But can we add this same create database query.
I tried this:
create database 'mydb' set engine='Innodb'
 but it throws error. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That concept does not exist: databases don't have engines; tables do.

**Update:**

The closest you can achieve is to change the default engine for CREATE TABLE statements that don't specify one, it's explained at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-setting.html